# mysql check date constraint (trigger)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Sorry for disturbing again, I completely new on MySql Maria DB (maybe on trigger as well) and looking to add check function to ensure no  past date is inserted in this table.
I believe that the only way to do it Mysql is to create a trigger.
I have tried to create one and I keep on having problems. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here (maybe I need a strong coffee):

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_date BEFORE INSERT on Event
  FOR EACH ROW 
  BEGIN 
  if new.date <= now() then
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Event cannot start in the past     event cannot start now. Choose an ulterior date'
end
end if;
```

Please that i'm on a terminal. Every time the system sees a semicolon it ends my query. I cannot therefore have 2 semicolons.

thanks for your help .
I hope im clear enough...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change delimiter before the query:

```
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER check_date BEFORE INSERT on Event
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF new.date <= now() THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Event cannot start in the past     event cannot start now. Choose an ulterior date';
  END IF;
END;//

delimiter ;
```

Also, end your `IF` statement before you `END` the entire block of code to execute for an event(trigger)