# Create a trigger to check if a birth date is valid or not

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've also read the other question but I didn't find a precise answer for it so plase don't flag it as duplicate.
So, I want to have a trigger to check if a DATE is a valid birth date.
So at the beggining I tried to create a custom constraint with `birth_date<NOW()` but I obviously got an error

Then I tried to use this trigger from the other question

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_birth_date
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON employee
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF( :new.emp_dob < date '1900-01-01' or 
      :new.emp_dob > sysdate )
  THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( 
      -20001, 
      'EMployee date of birth must be later than Jan 1, 1900 and earlier than today' );
  END IF;
END;
```

but I got syntax error because it's in Oracle and not in mySQL.

So, **How could I convert this into mySQL Trigger?**
I'm using MySQL Workbench 8.0

I'm still at my first tries with MySQL so I am not very good at it, so if you can I'd really aprreciate to know why you used somenthing and how if possibile :D

Thanks in advance

Comment: None of this code is mysql  - looks more like oracle to me?

Comment: Yes ik, how would the conversion be?

Comment: If you search for code that you want to use for mysql, it is useful to add "mysql" as a search term. See e.g. [mysql check date constraint (trigger)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40118653). Note: in MySQL, you need to have separate triggers for insert and update.

Comment: Note that you don't actually need a trigger for this.

Comment: @Strawberry how could I do it?

Comment: What's the version of MySQL (the server, *not* the Workbench) you're using? If it's high enough a simple check constraint could do it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
SELECT '2000-11-01' BETWEEN '1900-01-01' AND CURDATE() x;
+---+
| x |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+

SELECT '1899-11-01' BETWEEN '1900-01-01' AND CURDATE() x;
+---+
| x |
+---+
| 0 |
+---+

SELECT '2020-11-01' BETWEEN '1900-01-01' AND CURDATE() x;
+---+
| x |
+---+
| 0 |
+---+
```

So this could be adapted to something like:

```
INSERT INTO valid_dates
SELECT '2000-11-01' FROM (SELECT 1)a WHERE '2000-11-01' BETWEEN '1900-01-01' AND CURDATE();
```

Comment: I want to check it before inserting it, not when selecting the values

Comment: Suit yourself, but why?